# Transforming dataframe after reading from excel

Tags: pandas, excel, dataframe, apache-spark, azure-databricks

[image]
[image]
I have an excel file like image [1] and i want to transform it like shown in image 2. I want the result in delta table.

I tried it with creating pandas dataframe. and try to merge first row and header.

df.columns = np.concatenate([df.iloc[0, :2], df.columns[2:]])

df1 = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)

but still did not get the result i wanted,Because i could not merge all row values and header. i am using databricks.

Answer (score 0):

Create `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) :

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1])


out = df.rename_axis(['subject',None], axis=1).stack(0).reset_index()
print (out)
     name class  subject  1sem  2sem
0   Divya   1st  english    75    80
1   Divya   1st    maths    80    75
2   Divya   2nd  english    95    61
3   Divya   2nd    maths    75    90
4  Ravita   1st  english    96    67
5  Ravita   1st    maths    75    89
6  Ravita   2nd  english    93    90
7  Ravita   2nd    maths    89    90
```